# How to manually release all the queued jobs in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, api, queue

I need to know if there is a way to use the internal laravel api to force the release of all queued jobs. The reason is that we have a queue implementation and there we have a mechanism that releases the execution of a job  5 minutes, if there was a problem during the job execution. The problem is that is required to have some sort of refresh feature that triggers all of those "delayed" jobs manually, since we need a bit of control of when to run those delayed jobs, keeping the fail-safe mechanism intact. There is some way to implement this using Laravel??

Answer (score 0):

You can run the [php artisan queue:work](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queues#job-events) commando to start the Queue Work. If you wish start this from the code, you can call this [command programmatically](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/artisan#programmatically-executing-commands)

Comment: Thanks I'll test your suggestion and post here how it went.

Comment: I've tried and the work command option and yeah it can run the jobs, the strange thing is that it will wait for the time to complete for the job to run if it was released with some delay, so there is no way to force those jobs to run right away. :( Maybe I am missing something. I don't know.